# Can I save extremely washed out images in post-production?

Tags: raw, overexposure, exposure-correction

I shot a ton of pics today, and trying out Auto vs Aperture settings on my D5200, I did not realize that the ISO was set to the outrageous number it was. I got home to find that about 1/2 the shots I got today were just washed out. Is there a way to fix the shots that were taken today, or are they just a loss and learning experience? I shot in RAW and have access to Adobe Lightroom and Photoshop. I would greatly appreciate any input!

Comment: Did you take this in RAW or JPEG?

Comment: And, can you post a sample?

Comment: Also, what photo editing software are you using?

Comment: @ mattdm: I have AdobeCC, and so I have LR and PS. Having been a Web guy, and an IT guy for so long... LR is new to me, and I was so used to using Fireworks for so long... I think the last time I spent any time with PS was 2005. I have, but it is so different it is like I never knew anything. I will post the RAW image as soon as I can. I have my Laptop and my Desktop, the images were on my laptop. As soon as I crack that open again, I will post one. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good examples of RAW's advantages over JPEG?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/good-examples-of-raws-advantages-over-jpeg)

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/can-you-fix-incorrect-exposure-during-post-processing/7555#7555

Comment: @mattdm, I am on my laptop today and I have a bunch of the pics in RAW that are able to be shown as examples, and I am not sure how to post here for you to see. I have opened the pics in Ps and I tried to adjust the exposure, and that has not been at all helpful Looking forward to your reply. Thanks!

Comment: Please convert them to jpeg and then edit the question. There is a button for inserting images.

Comment: @DrewLatshaw: apart from what you are asking, I think there is something else wrong here. Even if you have your ISO at, say, 64000, in auto the camera should compensate itself, while in Aperture mode you are supposed to **at least** check the final image on the rear display. And I wrote at least because first of all you if you decide to shoot in manual you should look at the exposure value in the display before taking the photo. That said, every RAW developing tool has an Exposure Bias slider or similar. Try with that (and with HDR/Color Burn/and such)

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting the exposure is a basic feature of the "developing" software.  If you are shooting RAW images, you have more latitude in the image data than the normal presentation of such an image can handle, so you have some artistic interpretation to make there even when the photo captures the entire range of light available without error.  There is a slider for this, and a histogram and analysis tools to use whike doing so.

Since you had to ask, I think your real question is "what is workflow?" Or "I'm ready to take my camera off full-auto. What do I need to know?"

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think. I did say I am a newb. I also did say in my profile that I have a lot to learn about photography. Thanks though, I will look into the questions that you pointed out.