# What does ISO stand for?

Tags: terminology, iso

I've recently been learning how to use a camera, and was wondering what ISO stood for?

Comment: ISO doesn't actually stand for anything, it's the chosen short form for the name of the International Organisation for Standardisation.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/why-is-sensor-sensitivity-called-iso/34397#34397

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_speed#Current_system:_ISO) on Film Speed (under the ISO section) it stands for **International Organization for Standardization**.