# Where can I learn the theory behind photography and camera engineering?

Tags: theory, course

While I do have a basic understanding of the concepts of photography, it would be great to also understand the theoretical background behind the optics and the engineering of modern cameras. E.g. to learn what actually happens within the camera when a higher ISO setting is chosen.

Is there a book or a website focused on the theory rather than the practical applications? Perhaps some sort of an open university course in photographic theory?

Comment: [What is “ISO” on a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6615/15871)

Comment: [How is ISO implemented in digital cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2946/15871)

Comment: [Why is there an ISO setting when shooting raw?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/28983/15871)

Comment: [Is it better to shoot with a higher ISO, or use lower ISO and raise the exposure in post-processing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35136/15871)

Comment: [Is it really better to shoot at full-stop ISOs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43756/15871)

Comment: There are similar types of questions here for just about any of the technical aspects of cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *The Manual of Photography* (formerly [*The Ilford Manual of Photography*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilford_Manual_of_Photography) is in its [tenth edition](https://www.routledge.com/The-Manual-of-Photography/Allen-Triantaphillidou/p/book/9780240520377) after more than a century of publication. Ignore the equations and it provides a high level discussion. Investigate the equations and it provides a reasonable **introduction** to the science of photography. While the book is not inexpensive, it is cheaper than many photographic accessories and any new DSLR system lens.

Marc Levoy's [*Lectures on Digital Photography*](https://sites.google.com/site/marclevoylectures/home) is a more breezy and less technical series of videos, but very informative. The presentation benefits from [Levoy's experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Levoy) as a teacher and from his vocation as a leading edge photographic researcher.

Answer (score 1):

One of the very best (now out of print) available on the web is Kodak Digital Photoguide. Lark Books 67 Broadway Asheville NC 28801 by Michael A Guncheon.

Can't go wrong with this one. Short but chuck full of stuff you want. About $15 on the internet used.