# How does ISO setting change CCD/CMOS sensor behavior?

Tags: sensor, iso

In order to understand the technology in a digital camera, I considered the following question:

How does ISO setting change CCD/CMOS sensor behavior?

For example, does ISO setting affect the amount of charge that each photon generates in the sensor, or does it merely change the amplification of a fixed charge from each photon.  High end cameras allow for ISO in the range from 100 to e.g. 51200, thus a factor from 1 to 512, so it appears that the electronics allows for a pretty large range.  A reference to an article would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it could be a duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2946/how-is-iso-implemented-in-digital-cameras and/or http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/what-is-iso-on-a-digital-camera

Comment: @JamesSnell: Thanks for pointing to the two related questions, showing that this question is a duplicate.  I will delete the question in a couple of minutes, so you have a chance to read this comment.

Comment: @EquipDev Please *don't* delete the question. It will stay around marked as duplicate - these are helpful for people searching as you may well have used different terms, keywords etc to the earlier questions and this can then act as a "signpost" to the earlier questions.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Point taken; I will preserve the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know ISO settings do not change in any way the sensor behaviour. The "magic" is done after the signal is read from sensor. There is amplifier, which amplify the signal with value of ISO change.

And there is no way to change the power of photon as this is constant [value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon)

Comment: There are various ways it can be done - have a look at the linked questions for more information.  Sensor wells work on a charge basis, photons strike and release charge into the 'well', the amount released being something that can be controlled.

Comment: @JamesSnell, yes, the amount _after_ sensor can be controlled. But this do not change the semiconductor itself and the way it work