# Where is my DOF button in 550D?

Tags: canon, macro, reverse-mount

While going through many of the "reverse lens for macro shooting" tutorials I found that I should hold my DOF preview button and then detach the lens and reverse.
This would ensure the aperture lock. However, I haven't found any DOF preview button in my canon 550D DSLR. Or, am I missing something ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [DoF Preview button](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/what-is-the-depth-of-field-preview-button-on-my-dslr-supposed-to-show-me) is on the front of your camera, just below the lens release button.

[image: picture of a 550D with the DoF Preview button circled]

Comment: Thanks for the detail. :-) And I deserve that -3 points for being careless and not bothered to read the manual.

Answer (score 4):

On the front of the camera, bottom right of the lens mount (as you look at the front), small round button.