# How does a manual lens know when to adjust the aperture?

Tags: lens, aperture, viewfinder

When I look through a viewfinder before I take the photo, the lens is "wide open" - at its largest possible aperture (unless [the depth of field preview is used](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/what-is-the-depth-of-field-preview-button-on-my-dslr-supposed-to-show-me)). The aperture is adjusted to whatever I set it to just before the shot.

I understand it this way: *the camera tells the lens to adjust the aperture, makes a shot, and resets the aperture back to the max*.

But what about *manual* lenses like, e.g., the [Samyang 8mm FishEye f/3.5](http://www.syopt.com/en/product/photo-lenses-8mm-F3.5-UMC-FISH-EYE.php)? It does not have any connection to the camera (in fact, my D5000 shows *No lens attached* when I mount it). I set the aperture directly on the lens and the camera has no idea about its settings. Still, the viewfinder shows the scene very brightly, even if I set f/22.

How do such lenses know when to adjust the aperture? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nikon has a very noticable lever just inside the lens mount on the left side (viewing the body without the lens from the front).

[image: D500 Nikon body aperture lever]
<sup>Photo source: [Nikon D5000 DSLR: Announced and Previewed](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/2741052684/nikond5000)</sup>

On the lens there should be a matching lever. You can move it and see the diaphragm close.